# C# static constructor ordering

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

I am curious as to the order that static and instance constructors are fired. Could someone help me by letting me know what order the constructors below fire?

And what is the explanation behind this behaviour for the execution order of the static constuctors?

```
class A
    {
        static A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am in A's Static Constructor");
        }
        A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am in A's Default Constructor");
        }
    }

class B:A
{
    static B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in B's Static Constructor");
    }
    B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in B's Default Constructor");
    }
}
class C:B
{
    static C()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in C's Static Constructor");
    }
    C()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in C's Default Constructor");
    }
}
```

What will be the output of the following statement:

```
C c = new C();
```

Comment: Don't you have a compiler?

Comment: LinqPad makes it easy to test code like this.

Answer (score 5):

The order is:
C, B, A static ctors.
A, B, C, default ctors:

Update: Also see this great blog post ([Part1](https://ericlippert.com/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/) and [Part2](https://ericlippert.com/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two/)) from Eric Lippert on why static class initializers run in the reverse order than ctors.

Answer (score 4):

```
I am in C's Static Constructor
I am in B's Static Constructor
I am in A's Static Constructor
I am in A's Default Constructor
I am in B's Default Constructor
I am in C's Default Constructor
```

Comment: What is the explanation behind this behaviour for the execution order of the static constuctors?

Comment: See the updates in my answer for more background info on this topic.

Comment: I need a simple and understandable explanation.